# submitting form and calling node.js using axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have this page, and what it does is it is supposed to call the backend function `/updateServices` using axios on form submit.

```
 import '../../../styles/services.css';
    import axios from 'axios'
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    
    class AddServicesPage extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
      
          this.state = {
            siteLocation: '',
            Services: '',
            date: '',
            cnum: ''
          };
        }
      
        handleInputChange = e => {
          this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
          });
        };
      
        handleSubmit = e => {
          e.preventDefault();
      
          var date = Date().toLocaleString()
          const { siteLocation, Services, cnum } = this.state;
      
          const selections = {
            site: siteLocation,
            content: Services,
            updatedByCNUM: cnum,
          };
      
          axios
            .post(`/updateServices`, selections) 
              .then(() =>
                      console.log("updating"),
                      window.location = "/admin/services"
              )
              .catch(function(error) {
                  // alert(error)
                  window.location = "/admin/services/new"
              })
        };
      
      
    
        render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
               <div id="form-main">
                <div id="form-div">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
                      
                    <select name="siteLocation" id="siteLocation" onChange={this.handleInputChange} >
                        <option value="OTT">Ottawa</option>
                        <option value="MAR">Markham</option>
                    </select>
    
                    <p className="email">
                        <input name="Services" type="text" className="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="Services" placeholder="Services" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    </p>
                  
                   <p className="cnum">
                        <input name="cnum" type="text" className="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="cnum" placeholder="cnum" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                    </p>
                    
                    
                    
                    <div className="submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
                        <div className="ease"></div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <a href="/tour">Get Results{'->'}</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
        }
    }
    
    export default AddServicesPage;
```

however, it is not even hitting the backend on form submit, and is skipping it and going down to the `.then` saying it is working. in the backend, In my `/updateServices`, it doesn't even log anything. it logs nothing, not even an empty line, which means it is never hitting the backend. is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Are you sure you have put your backend API endpoint  URL correctly? 
As in the above snippet you are only calling `/updateServices` in your API call, is axios configured with the correct API domain? 
If that's a yes then I think you have to check your backend routes, it might be intercepted way earlier than you expect & responding with nothing but a `200 OK`,

Also as an added tip, consider routing your React application with React router, do not use window.location since it will always refresh your page & will lose your React App context.

Comment: Is your frontend and backend running on the same port?

Comment: @iunfixit backend is 3001, frontend is 3000

Comment: @HasinthaAbeykoon thx 4 the tips. it is strange cause it just stopped working today. never had this problem and no code changed .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have not setup the path in your `axios` call correctly.

You are calling `/updateServices` without it pointing to any domain.

```
axios.post(`/updateServices`, selections)
```

You are supposed to pass a domain and then a route. For example, if your backend is running on your localhost at port 5000, then your call should look like

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/updateServices`, selections)
```

If you want to use axios the way you have to put in your code, you can do that like the example below:

```
const backend = axios.create({baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000'});
backend.post(`/updateServices`, selections)
```

I would use this pattern, if I have to make multiple calls to the same domain. Also, I would put the `axios create` in a separate file and import it from there where ever needed.

Comment: thanks 4 the answer. but in the backend, I have a port defined and it hits that before every call. however, I put it in all the ways you showed, just to test it out, and it still doesn't work. it is strange.

Comment: Try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in the examples above. Can you please share your updated code, if this one does not work, along with the port that your server is running on ?

Comment: ok so putting those in, it takes away the error with the proxy. the error was, couldn't send from 3000 to 3001 or something. but it still doesn't send to the backend. I cannot reach any post request from my node.js file. backend is running 3001, and front end is running 3000

Comment: also, I the proxy set up in my package.json as localhost:3001, so it talks to it there. I think that part is fine as its been working, but what's strange is the fact that I now cannot reach any request at the backend. any path I try to hit with the axios call through post is failing. by failing I mean not even hitting it

Comment: Great answer, If you have tried this, I would rather consider on revising my backend routes, since usually routes are intercepted sequentially, my best guess is you have your endpoint intercept by another route match before your expected one. I think more help can be provided if you can show us how your routes/endpoints are configured in your backend server!